# Can a user update the script in a console and access other users' data in my firebase code?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, security, authentication

For context, I display my Firebase app's configuration in the app.js file (is this safe?) and in order to give a user their data I list the following code:

```
db.collection('whispers').where("sender", "array-contains", 
userID).orderBy('time').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
changes.forEach(change => {
       renderSay(change.doc);
 });
});
```

Could a user remove the 'where' condition and access all data in this collection? I only use anonymous sign in so nothing special required in accessing their own data besides using the same device and not clearing data.

Comment: You generally have to assume that a Browser user could do anything your server allows. They could send any type of request, and see all data that is theoretically available to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that could be possible by reverse-engineering but the actual security lies in the security rules.
You can change them from the Firebase Console
Here is a video from [Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw) and here is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Match any document in the 'users' collection
    match /users/{userID} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid === userID;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid === userID;
    }
  }
}
```

Using the above security rules will allow users to read and write their data ONLY.
So even if they reverse-engineer your code, it will harm their data only and other data will be safe.
For more details please check the links above and you will get familiar with wildcard [`{userID}` in this case]

*PS: Only you or anyone with access to your Firebase Console can change the rules*

EDIT: [This Medium Article](https://medium.com/@khreniak/cloud-firestore-security-rules-basics-fac6b6bea18e) has many types of rules explained. Please have a read there too :D

Comment: Great info here. In my case I created a collection for users, could a user query that collection from the front end by changing the javascript code? I'm only beginning to learn about security rules so I'm wondering how exposed my data is as of now.

Comment: @user3385829 I doubt yes they can reverse-engineer the code. I am not sure cause I have not done that anytime. But to be on the safer side use security rules. If you want users to access their data only then use the above rules. If you want something specific then please elaborate so I can help you in that way.